# SQL Server : update a table based on the result of another table with substring

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, substring

I have 2 tables in my database, one of them contains a `Description` and a `Code` columns

Table_1

```
Description  |  Code
--------------------
123 street      23
321 street2     12
342 blabla      1
```

The other table has an Id column, and a description column

Table_2

```
Id  |  Description
------------------------------  
41     street (textidontwant)
22     street2 (textidontwant)
33     blabla (textidontwant)
```

Basically, what I want to do is update the `Code` from Table 1 with the `Id` from table 2, however I need to use a substring to trim the description from Table 2 in order for the text to be matched with the description from Table 1.

I've already written the subquery, which is the following:

```
SELECT LEFT([Description], CHARINDEX('(', [Description]) - 1)) FROM Table_2
```

This right here trims the text inside the parenthesis just fine, but the problem is that I can't seem to be able to update Table_1 Code column with the Id from Table_2

I tried doing this:

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Code = (SELECT T2.Id FROM Table_2 T2)
WHERE Table_1.[Description] = (SELECT LEFT([Description], CHARINDEX('(', [Description]) - 1)) FROM Table_2)
```

but I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sub queries. Sql server allows you to use Joins in update statements.

```
UPDATE T1
SET Code = T2.Id
FROM Table_1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 T2 
    ON T1.[Description] = LEFT(T2.[Description], CHARINDEX('(', T2.[Description]) - 1)
```